# Grails java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application Grails 2.5.0 (not a test class)

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to upgrade a Grails 1.2.x project to the minimum version which supports JDK 1.8 (=Grails 2.5.0) so that I modify the written code as less as possible.
After I managed to resolve all the dependencies, create the .war file and start it (on a jBoss 7 server) I get the mentioned error in the title when from a Controller class I do a call such as Result.list() (the Result being the domain class).
I do have multiple datasources configured, it seems the jndi names are OK and I can connect to the used DB (I got errors when these were not OK).
I tried to put @Validateable as I red somewhere on the class, but no use.
Any ideas or tips what could I try else? I suspect it is something related to DB, not have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: show some code..

Comment: FYI... There really are no good technical reasons to update a Grails 1.2.x app to Grails 2.5.0 right now.  If you want to upgrade to 2.5.x you should upgrade to 2.5.6 which will be the same effort but will include more improvements.  2.5.6 has been stable for quite a long time.

Comment: Can you show the source code for the domain class in question and also show or describe the context from which you are invoking the GORM method that throws the error?

Comment: In the meantime we concluded that it is better to rewrite everything (since it is a smaller app) in another stack, probably Spring + JSP + Maven.
The conclusion from some colleagues with Groovy/Grails experience was anyway that for a migration from 1.2.x to 2.5.x takes a lot of effort, and since the client doesn't have neither expertise on their end, it is better to switch technologies altogether.
Thank you guys for the fast responses!